# Does Java thread-safety apply to all instances of a class or just shared instances?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, static-methods

I'm trying to determine if I need to be worried about thread-safety in a few crucial classes I have written. I've read several articles/existing SO questions, and I keep seeing the same, recurring definition of thread-safety:

> *Thread Safety* means that the fields of an object or class always maintain a valid state, as observed by other objects and classes, **even when used concurrently by multiple threads.**

OK. I *kind* of get it. But there's a very big piece of the puzzle I'm missing here:

**Does thread-safety only come into play when the *same* instance of a class is being used by multiple threads, or just when *any* 2+ instances are being used?**

#### Example #1:

Say I have a `Dog` class that contains no static methods or fields, and let's say I have 5 different instances of a `Dog` that are being operated on from inside 5 different threads. Do I need to be concerned about thread-safety? I would say "no", because there are no static fields/methods, and each thread has its own instance of `Dog` whose state exists independently of the other 4 instances. **(1) Is this correct? If not, why?**

#### Example #2:

Now let's say I add a static method to `Dog`:

```
public void woof() {
    this.isWoofing = true;
}

public static void makeWoof(Dog dog) {
    dog.woof();
}
```

Do I need to be concerned about thread-safety now? Each thread has its own instance of a `Dog`, but now they are sharing the same static `makeWoof()` method, which changes the state of the `Dog` it is operating on. I still say "no". **(2) Is this correct? If not, why?**

Given these 2 examples, it seems to me that thread-safety is only an issue when multiple threads are operating on the *same instance* of a class. But the minute you give each thread its own instance, it seems that I can do anything I want to that instance and not worry about what's going on inside the other threads. **(3) Is this correct? If not, why? Are they any exceptions to this?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think of static fields (those belonging to the class) as fields of a "class instance", like they are sometimes called in other languages where classed are treated as objects (smalltalk comes to mind). Since classes are global, every thread can access and possibly modify these. Otherwise the same rules apply as to every other object. But if these are no static fields as in your example, static methods can not modify them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumptions about thread safety are correct.  It boils down to fields/state on the same `instance` being modified by multiple threads.

In your first question the threads all manipulate their own instance of `Dog` so the approach is thread safe.

In the second question the instance is passed into the static method so once again your working with different instances of the class.  If the `Dog` class contained static fields and the static method manipulated those fields that would not be thread safe, but non final static fields are really never thread safe.

Comment: @TicketMonster Exactly static fields and sharing instances are where you should be concerned.

Comment: Thanks again! If I simply `synchronize` a static field - is that typically sufficient to make it thread-safet?

Comment: I would avoid storing state in static fields altogether.  Try to reserve the use of static fields for things like constants.

Comment: @TicketMonster I'm going to stand strongly beside this answer.  I created a Gist to illustrate CPerkins statements: https://gist.github.com/kmb385/6392037

Answer (score 5):

**It's not really about shared instances.  It's about shared state**

With that in mind:

1: correct - if your threads do not operate on shared state, they are inherently thread safe.

2: Incorrect (sorta): - In the specific example of this specific static method, no shared state is touched, but static methods can create/maninpulate shared state.

3: See 1 and 2

As an example, let's introduce a small bit of shared state into the OP's `Dog` class:

```
    static Integer numberOfBarksToday=0;
```

Because it's static, it's shared.  So now, a static method (a modified version of the OP's `makeWoof` method) can manipulate that:

```
    public static void makeWoof(Dog dog) {
        dog.woof();
        synchronized(Dog.numberOfBarksToday) {
            Dog.numberOfBarksToday++;
        }
    }
```

I just realized that when I created the example above, I synchronized the access out of habit.   With that synchronization, this particular access is thread-safe (though of course all other accesses to numberOfBarksToday have to be synchronized as well).

Without the synchronization, with multiple threads calling this method, you will tend to undercount the number of barks today:
T0) numberOfBarksToday=0;
T1) thread A checks number of barks (first part of `++`), gets 0.
T2) thread B checks number of barks, gets 0.
T3) thread A sets number of barks to 1
T4) thread B sets number of barks to 1

And that's without considering whether in the shared object, the assignment method is atomic.

The synchronization prevents all of the above, plus introduces a memory barrier so that all threads see the same value for numberOfBarksToday.

Comment: Thanks @CPerkins (+1) - can you explain how my `makeWoof(Dog)` method could introduce thread safety issues?

Comment: @Perkins in the second method he is passing in the instance of `Dog` the method will only touch fields on that instance. Just my opinion, but think about all the static `StringUtils` classes that exist that operate on `String` instances they are thread safe.  The static method won't be able to modify any fields except for those on the instance, since `this` is not allowed.  Not trying to give you a rough time, just trying to see if there is something I'm missing.

Comment: @TicketMonster - in your **specific example as written**, it can't. But static methods give the opportunity to manipulate shared state without ever sharing instances.  See edit.

Comment: @CPerkins Could you provide an example where shared state would be manipulated via a static method? I would gladly upvote.

Comment: Thanks, I think we were on the same page all along.  I didn't realize you were referring to static fields in your answer.  Hopefully the OP will revisit this.

Comment: Thanks, we totally are on one page. Your answer is completely correct.  I just felt the need to underline that even if you don't have two threads sharing one instance of a class (two threads, one Dog in this instance), you still can have shared state.

Answer (score 2):

You asked about how a static method *might* potentially introduce threading concerns.  Below I provided a code example with comments.  Note that nothing stops non-static methods from modifying static variables, so the static method is not necessarily more "dangerous" than the instance method.

As CPerkins pointed out, it's most pragmatic to think of threading concerns in terms of "shared state" vs. "unshared state" instead of in terms of classical programming scopes like "class-level (static) variable" "instance-level (member) variable", "private variable", "public variable", "class-level method", "instance-level method".  Following some best-practices with regards to classic OO scoping can help guide you towards writing thread-safe code, but ultimately it is the programmer's responsibility to track down what is and isn't shared between threads, and coordinate access (read/write) to shared resources appropriately.

```
public class Dog
{
    private static boolean isWagging;
    private boolean isWoofing;

    public void woof()
    {
        this.isWoofing = true;
    }

    public static void wag()
    {
        isWagging = true;
    }

    public static void makeWoof(Dog dog)
    {
        /**
         * Thread safety: woof() only modifies instance variables of 'Dog'.
         * So if no dog instances are shared between threads, then no
         * instance variables of any Dog are shared between threads, and so
         * (as long as we do not share any Dog across threads) then there is
         * no concern about needing to control access to shared state. Note
         * that woof() *could* be changed to also modify 'isWagging' which
         * is a static variable, and thus not protected by the "Dog
         * instances are not shared between threads" contract. There is no
         * guarantee that just because a method is an "instance" method, it
         * will not modify shared state. It is a good general practice for
         * member methods to only modify member variables, but sometimes
         * modifying shared state (e.g. a database) in a member method is
         * somewhat unavoidable.
         */
        dog.woof();

        /**
         * Thread safety: wag() is a static method that operates on a static
         * variable. Instances of Dog do not get separate copies of static
         * variables, as the nature of 'static' means that the variable is
         * attached to the Dog _class_ itself, not to _instances_ of the Dog
         * class. You could say that, in the current implementation, if
         * *any* dog wags, then all dogs will be marked as wagging, which is
         * probably not what we want. Additionally, since there is no
         * synchronization mechanism being used, there is no guarantee that
         * other threads will see that that the value of 'isWagging' has
         * been updated.
         */
        wag();

        /**
         * Additional note: Java makes the static/non-static issue confusing
         * by allowing the following syntax to compile. The following syntax
         * *might* lead some programmers to believe that some dogs can be
         * wagging while others are not. Most compilers will warn you about
         * this syntax because it misleadingly makes it appear as if
         * isWagging is an instance variable, and wag is an instance method
         * (which is not the case.)
         */
        if (!dog.isWagging)
        {
            dog.wag();
        }

        /**
         * To be less ambiguous, you should really write the above code as:
         */
        if (!isWagging)
        {
            wag();
        }

        /**
         * Or even better: do not use any non-final static variables in your
         * program at all.
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Good explanation!  I get the point about static variables, but as you elude to static fields are not the best place to store state.  Using statics, you can fall into state issues without multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Example #1 - You are correct.

If we can show that some object is only every visible to a single thread, then it is said to be *thread confined*.  There are no thread-safety issues for a thread-confined object ... and your `Dog` instances are thread confined.

Example #2 - You are correct.

The fact that you are using a `static` method doesn't change anything here.  Given the example as you have described it, the `Dog` instances are still thread-confined.

Example #3 - Assuming that all of the objects under consideration are thread-confined, there are no exceptions.

---

Note that if you changed the `woof` method in example #2 to use some shared state (e.g. a `static` variable) then thread-safety would potentially be a concern.

The other thing to note is that it may be difficult to know if and when instances are going to be thread-confined.  There are two strategies for dealing with this:

- You can make the `Dog` class thread-safe by making the relevant methods thread-safe.  This means that you don't need to analyse the usage patterns, but your application may end up doing *unnecessary* synchronization.
- You can leave it in the hands of the classes that *use* the `Dog` class to synchronize externally if required.

Comment: Could you provide your thoughts on CPerkins answer regarding thread safety in the static method?  OP seems to have a lingering question.

Comment: @KevinBowersox - I think that CPerkins answer to 2) has introduced a red-herring ... and that has confused the OP.  The right answer to 2) is "correct".

Answer (score 0):

(1) Yes

(2) Yes, if the method does NOT operate on any non-final static fields. No, otherwise

(3) Yes, for exceptions see (2).